# Popup Box in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I create a popup box that will appear when I click the Add to Cart button in asp.net mvc? The Popup Box should have 2 button "Sign Up" and "Log In", and this buttons should be redirected to the Sign Up or Log In page.

I tried to use a modal but I'm not sure if it's the right choice, here's the code.

```
                        <a class="shortcode_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".firstmodal"> Add to Cart</a>
                        <div class=" modal fade firstmodal">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">

                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal"> <span>&times;</span> </button>
                                        <div class="modal-title"> MODAL KEME </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <h4>Don't have an account yet?</h4>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                <a href="/Account/Register" class="shortcode_button">Sign Up</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <a href="/Account/Login" class="shortcode_button">Log In</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Show the code you've made and tried yourself first

Comment: this may can helps you, http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3095/best-approach-to-handle-login-popup-dialog-using-mvc-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use either Jquery pop up,kendo or telerik pop up or fancy pop up.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) or, even easier, a plugin that allows to use it with a simple api, like [BootboxJs](http://bootboxjs.com/):

```
bootbox.dialog({
  message: "I am a custom dialog",
  title: "Custom title",
  buttons: {
    success: {
      label: "Sign Up",
      className: "btn-success",
      callback: function() {
        Example.show("great success");
      }
    },
    main: {
      label: "Login",
      className: "btn-primary",
      callback: function() {
        Example.show("Primary button");
      }
    }
  }
});
```